# Running MsTest throws "Load" method does not have an implementation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

After upgrading from TFS 2008 to 2010 and running crazy having the build to properly run unit tests.
When running unit tests from build or command line I get the error:
Loading C:\Builds\159....\Binaries\Mixed Platforms\Release....UnitTest.dll...
C:\Builds\159....\Binaries\Mixed Platforms\Release.....UnitTest.dll
Method 'Load' in type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.TestMethod' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel,
 Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' does not have an implementation.

Does any anyone have any clue, other then an repair of the VS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by some assembly redirect in unit test's app.config, which was redirecting System.Xml and one other assembly to 2.0 framework.

Probable mstest is replacing the original exception with a new one....